# Setting a non-nil object to a weak property returns nil second time but not first one

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, weak-references

I'm working on a legacy app which I'm refactoring, and there is a weird behavior I don't understand.

There is a `UIViewController` called `CANoContentViewController` and it has a simple initialization code from a Nib:

```
+ (CANoContentViewController *)instantiateController {
   CANoContentViewController *vc = [[CANoContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CANoContentViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   DLog(@"Created CANoContentViewController %@", vc);
   return vc;
}
```

Then, other `UIViewController` shows it if there is no content to show. Here is the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *noContentViewController;

-(void)showOrDeleteNoContentIfNeeded{
   if([self.proposals count] <= 0) { // Show No Content VC
       self.noContentViewController = [CANoContentViewController instantiateController];
       DLog(@"Set CANoContentViewController %@", self.noContentViewController);
       self.noContentViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
       [self addChildViewController:self.noContentViewController];
       [self.view addSubview:self.noContentViewController.view];
       [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
   } else {
       [self.noContentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
       [self.noContentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
       [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
   }
}
```

The problem here is that first time `CANoContentViewController` is shown, all works fine, and the logs are as expected:

```
2018-06-12 00:58:29.303276+0200 Base[11828:838463] +[CANoContentViewController instantiateController](0x105cc6688) Created CANoContentViewController <CANoContentViewController: 0x7fc350e101f0>
2018-06-12 00:58:29.303517+0200 Base[11828:838463] -[CAProposalsViewController showOrDeleteNoContentIfNeeded](0x7fc35106b200) Set CANoContentViewController <CANoContentViewController: 0x7fc350e101f0>
```

As you can see, the created controller is set correctly in the property.

The second time this code is executed, even being a new instance of the parent view controller which will instantiate `CANoContentViewController` the `CANoContentViewController` is created correctly as logs shows, but it's not set to the property:

```
2018-06-12 00:58:31.379708+0200 Base[11828:838463] +[CANoContentViewController instantiateController](0x105cc6688) Created CANoContentViewController <CANoContentViewController: 0x7fc350c8bca0>
2018-06-12 00:58:31.380275+0200 Base[11828:838463] -[CAProposalsViewController showOrDeleteNoContentIfNeeded](0x7fc35181f200) Set CANoContentViewController (null)
```

So the app crashes because it's trying to set a `nil` object in method `addChildViewController`.

Anyone knowns why second time this line doesn't works and the property is `nil`?

```
self.noContentViewController = [CANoContentViewController instantiateController];
```

I've checked that when I change the property to `strong` all works great. But I can't understand why is this happening because every time the `CANoContentViewController` is created from a new parent view controller which `self.noContentViewController` property should be different to the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your execute:

```
self.noContentViewController = [CANoContentViewController instantiateController];
```

there is no longer any strong reference to the object you created and assigned to the weak property so it gets deallocated and the weak property becomes nil. The fact it works the first time is just luck and can't be counted on.

If you want the instance to survive long enough to work on it in that method, assign to a local variable.

```
-(void)showOrDeleteNoContentIfNeeded{
   if([self.proposals count] <= 0) { // Show No Content VC
       CANoContentViewController *controller = [CANoContentViewController instantiateController];
       self.noContentViewController = controller;
       DLog(@"Set CANoContentViewController %@", self.noContentViewController);
       self.noContentViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
       [self addChildViewController:self.noContentViewController];
       [self.view addSubview:self.noContentViewController.view];
       [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
   } else {
       [self.noContentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
       [self.noContentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
       [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
   }
}
```

The use of the local variable will keep a strong reference during the scope of the local variable. This holds the reference long enough to call `addChildViewController` which creates another strong reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now. Btw it's the same than setting this property as `strong`? If not, which of two ways is a better solution?

Comment: Using the local variable is needed if your property is weak. If your property is strong then it works for the same reason - there is a strong reference keeping the instance around long enough. Whether you make your `noContentViewController` property strong or weak is a separate decision independent of this issue. weak is often used to avoid reference cycles such as in a parent/child dual reference. Use strong if you need the class with the `noContentViewController` property to "own" the reference until it decides it is done with it. Use weak otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Setting your property as a `strong` reference should work because the reference is not released due to still keeps a reference pointer.

For example set:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *noContentViewController
```

Instead of:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *noContentViewController
```